# Orderby on left join null value

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Following situation:

- Table of users
- Table of addresses
- The user has a single **optional** reference to the address table (=left join)

The query to fetch the data is:

```
IQueryable<User> query = 
    from u in _dbContext.Users
        join a in _dbContext.Address on u.AddressId equals a.Id into address
        from addresses in address.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new User(u, a);
```

Now I want to do a sorting on the query based on the municipality of the address

```
query = query.OrderBy(u => u.Address.Municipality);
```

The problem is that the Address can be a null value (as the address is optional) and for that reason it is throwing following exception.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is there a way to order on the municipality knowing that it can be null?

Already tried following things with same outcome:

```
query = query.OrderBy(u => u.Address.Municipality ?? "");
query = query.OrderBy(u => u.Address == null).ThenBy(u => u.Address.Municipality);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`query = query.OrderBy(u => u.Address.Municipality.HasValue);`

Comment: This will not help when `Address` is null. Also the OP would like to order on the **value** of `Municipality`, not whether it has a value or not. `u.Address?.Municipality` might be a better option.

Comment: Also tried u.Address?.Municipality but then you get following error: An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

Comment: @onursahin07 As slugster pointed out: you can't use the hasvalue as the Address is null

Comment: Okey try this one query = query.OrderBy(u => u.Address != null ? u.Address.Municipality : "");

Answer (score 0):

You can write your comparer like this:

```
        public class One
        {
            public int A { get; set; }
        }

        public class Two
        {
            public string S { get; set; }
        }

        public class T
        {
            public One One { get; set; }
            public Two Two { get; set; }
        }

        public class OrderComparer : IComparer<Two>
        {
            public int Compare(Two x, Two y)
            {
                if (((x == null) || (x.S == null)) && ((y == null) || (y.S == null)))
                    return 0;

                if ((x == null) || (x.S == null))
                    return -1;

                if ((y == null) || (y.S == null))
                    return 1;

                return x.S.CompareTo(y.S);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new List<T> {
                new T{ One = new One{A=1}, Two = new Two{ S="dd" } },
                new T{ One = new One{A=5}, Two = null },
                new T{ One = new One{A=0}, Two = new Two{ S=null } },
                new T{ One = new One{A=6}, Two = new Two{ S="aa" } },
            };

            var comparer = new OrderComparer();

            collection = collection.OrderBy(e => e.Two, comparer).ToList();
        }
```

But in your case you have to write `var collection = query.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.Address)`.

Also there is other method:

```
var result = query.Where(x=>x.Address==null || x.Address.Municipality==null)
.Union(query.Where(x.Address!=null && x.Address.Municipality!=null).OrderBy(x=>x.Address.Municipality));
```

Comment: First solution seems like alot of work for something basic :) Second option doesn't work: same exception is being throwed 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Linq clearly can't handle it

Comment: So you have problems not with nullable Address. Maybe, your DbContext is null.

Comment: No i have problem with nullable address. If I do orderby on other fields (that are not null) it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple demo and it works well when I add nullable foreign key to the two tables.

Besides, I do not understabd what is `select new User(u, a);` in your code.

Below is my sample code:

Models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }
    public string Municipality { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
IQueryable<User> query =
        from u in _context.Users
        join a in _context.Address on u.AddressId equals a.Id into address
        from addresses in address.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new User
        { 
            Id = u.Id,
            Name = u.Name,
            AddressId = u.AddressId,
            Address = addresses
        };

query = query.OrderBy(u => u.Address.Municipality);
```